# Is it possible to use WebClient while having spring profiles in the application?

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty, spring-profiles

I have a spring boot project with Profiles namely - "scheduler","instantScheduler" .
In this project we are using WebClient for calling the external api's.

Attaching the webConfig file here :

```
  private ClientHttpConnector connector() {
    return new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.newConnection()));
  }

  @Bean
  public WebClient webClientConfiguration() {

    int memoryLimit = Integer.parseInt("10");

    ExchangeStrategies exchangeStrategies =
        ExchangeStrategies.builder()
            .codecs(
                configurer -> configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(1024 * 1024 * memoryLimit))
            .build();
    return WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(connector())
        .exchangeStrategies(exchangeStrategies)
        .build();
  }
```

While the app runs smoothly in the default profile , while I try to run it by setting any other profile as active using the vm commands ,

I run into the following error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null 
at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient.<clinit>(HttpClient.java:940) ~[reactor-netty-0.9.2.RELEASE.jar!/:0.9.2.RELEASE] 
at com.octanner.initiatives.config.WebClientConfig.connector(WebClientConfig.java:22)
```

and

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1 
at java.base/java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
```

Is there any way I can modify by WebClient so that we can have profiles also co-exist in the application ?